# 2 out of 3 Computers cannot create App Package

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, uwp

So I wanted to create App Packages (Store -> Create App Packages) via Visual Studio 2015 but it fails. 3 People worked on this project. 2 of us cannot create app packages and one of us can.

But we still wonder. Why cannot everyone create app packages? Here are some error examples:

> Error: "A certificate with thumbprint '*thumbprint here*' that is specified in the project cannot be found in the certificate store. Please specify a valid thumbprint in the project file."

> Error: "Cannot import the key file '*key file here*'. The key file may be password protected. To correct this, try to import the certificate manually into the current user's personal certificate store."

> Error: "The certificate specified is not valid for signing. For more information about valid certificates, see *microsoft link here*"

> Error (This error is there mutliple times): "The name '*name here*' does not exist in the namespace "using: '*namespace here*'."

Any Ideas what I can do?

Comment: All those errors give either explicit instructions on what to do (the first 3), or implicit instructions (that last 1).  Creating packages with certificates will be problematic if you don't all have the same certificate installed in the same way on each machine.  Uninstall the certificate on all machines and then ensure that it's installed 100% exactly the same, *specifically the location!*

Comment: Sound like you might need to import a sercurity certificate used to sign your code. Are there any ".cer" or "pfx" files needed for your build?

Comment: Check if your `[AppName]_TemporaryKey.pfx` is checked in on your Version Control. If not, make sure you include it in your Version Control Service.If not, you can have the other two users create a temporary key and then Build the application. See [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/create-certificate-package-signing)